# Calling a function inside the body, from an external JS file which is dynamically loading

Tags: javascript

I have an external JS file:

```
console.log("DEBUG1");

function Function1() {
    console.log("DEBUG2");
}

function Function2() {
    console.log("DEBUG3");
}
```

I want to load this JS file dinamically in the head and then call the function Function1() inside the body, before the body onLoad event occurs. [Here](http://pastebin.com/eheYaHjA), I've tried [all these solutions](http://ntt.cc/2008/02/10/4-ways-to-dynamically-load-external-javascriptwith-source.html): only the first one works, but I would like to avoid it.

For example, solution 2 is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].getElementsByTagName("script")[0].src = "JS.js";
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onLoad="javascript:Function2();">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Function1();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I solve this (without using solution 1)?

Answer (score 0):

use `onreadystatechange` event of script tag.

check this link
http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html

Answer (score 0):

```
var script_tag = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
script_tag.onload = function() {
  Function1();
}
script_tag.src = "JS.js";
```

Comment: That's not good for me: I would finish to read the JS before arriving at the end of the body, as I tested here: http://lucaghio.webege.com/Prova5/2/2.html